# Is it possible to disable or skip nighttime in Horizon?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

From what I can tell, nighttime doesn't really play any important role in the game unless a mission forces it. I'd love to play always in daytime - is it possible to skip or disable night in Horizon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way to fix or manually change the day/night cycle. Many people have commented on that in various threads, such as [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/horizon/comments/5wx8wp/horizon_sleep_skip_time/):

> There doesn't seem to be a rest option that we are used to. The only thing I've noticed is when I hit a Campfire to save. There is a bit of a cut off during the manual save as well as if you incurred any damage it seems to replenish lost health. Spoiler. Other than that no I haven't come across any way to actually rest/fast forward the time cycle.

As well as [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168644-horizon-zero-dawn/75045531):

> Don't think you can. I haven't come across any daytime restricted activities tho so it doesn't matter.

For what it's worth, during the 50-60 hours I played, I was also unable to find any way to manually alter the day/night cycle.

Answer (score 1):

If you play on pc you can just go to a campfire and keep pressing quick save like 10-15 times. You don't need to wait the fade in-out effect, just press same button like 2-3 times per second and it fast forwards whole night.